# cassandra sstable-loader error: "Got an unknow host from describe_ring()"

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, nodes

I am trying to load **sstables** to cassandra cluster of two nodes with **sstable-loader** utility provided in cassandra 0.8.4

1) I have loaded the data successfully on single node environment .
 2) As i have created the cluster of two nodes ,while loading ,after gossip it throws exception

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Got an unknow host from describe_ring()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in 0.8.4 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3044). It's fixed in 0.8.5; you can test that by following the link on the release thread [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-dev/201109.mbox/%3CCAKkz8Q12k2o7ZM5Uy9hxNk7kYEsQidwcyXbq_uZFnA+YaTYXLA@mail.gmail.com%3E).